# Slow Request/Response - Google OCR API

Tags: android, performance, request, ocr, google-vision

I'm coding an app with Android Studio using the Optical Character Recognition API of Google.

I'm basically directly retrieving data from the picture taken by the Camera, encoding it in Base64 and low resolution (resulting in a byte array with a size of 300KB).

I run this code in a thread in order to make the request with this base64 encoded image, but the response returned by the server is kind of slow (about 9-10 seconds).

Also, according to the Google Console, the requests i made, have an average latency of 1000ms.

Is it normal or am i doing something wrong ? Is there any way i could decrease this latency ?

```
if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("requestDataToAPI",false)){ // Scan effectué
        String[] photoBase64 = {getIntent().getStringExtra("photoBase64")};
        LoadDataFromImage task = new LoadDataFromImage(this);
        task.execute(photoBase64);
    }
```

---

Thread handling the request :

```
private class LoadDataFromImage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private Context ctx;

    public LoadDataFromImage (Context context){
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        mDialog.setMessage("Analyse de la photo ...");
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... photoBase64) {
        Vision.Builder visionBuilder = new Vision.Builder( new NetHttpTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null);
        String cleAPI = getString(R.string.google_vision_ocr_api_key); // CLE PRIVEE ---> vous DEVEZ vous procurer votre propre clé avec Google
        visionBuilder.setVisionRequestInitializer(new VisionRequestInitializer(cleAPI));
        vision = visionBuilder.build();

        // Type d'analyse d'image
        Feature desiredFeature = new Feature();
        desiredFeature.setType("TEXT_DETECTION");

        Image inputImage = new Image();
        inputImage.encodeContent(com.google.api.client.util.Base64.decodeBase64(photoBase64[0]));
        AnnotateImageRequest request = new AnnotateImageRequest();
        request.setImage(inputImage);
        request.setFeatures(Arrays.asList(desiredFeature));

        BatchAnnotateImagesRequest batchRequest = new BatchAnnotateImagesRequest();
        batchRequest.setRequests(Arrays.asList(request));

        // Réponse du serveur
        BatchAnnotateImagesResponse batchResponse = new BatchAnnotateImagesResponse();
        try {
            batchResponse = vision.images().annotate(batchRequest).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Impossible d'accéder à la reconnaissance de textes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("API Run :", e.toString());
        }

        final TextAnnotation text = batchResponse.getResponses().get(0).getFullTextAnnotation();
        if(text != null){
            String textReceived = text.getText();
            System.out.println(textReceived);
            return textReceived;
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        mDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        addName.setText(result);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facture transférée", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you can upload your images to Google Storage instead of internal storage/sd card in the first place, I believe that is the best approach, both for simplicity and performance. Please be sure to comment on this issue after you've tried it! We really appreciate hearing about real-world experiences.